# Moving Unity GameObjects spawned through Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I am trying to make some coins I spawn trough Instantiate, to float up and down. This is the code I currently have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Coin : MonoBehaviour{  
    public bool  isopen;

    [SerializeField]
    private float Speed = 1f;

    [Header("Sliding Configs")]
    [SerializeField]
    
    
    private Vector3 SlideDirection = Vector3.up;
    [SerializeField]
    private float SlideAmount = 1f;
    private Vector3 StartPosition;

    private Coroutine AnimationCoroutine;

    public bool diadromos = true;
    public float[] CoinR =  { 0 , 0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 };
    public GameObject coin;
    public GameObject spawned;
    public List<GameObject> allSpawns = new List<GameObject>();
    
     public void Start(){

        CoinR[5] = 4;
    }


     
        public void Update(){


            CoinR[0] = -51;     CoinR[1] = -32;     CoinR[2] = 1;     CoinR[3] = -24;     CoinR[4] = -20; 
         
            if (diadromos ==true){
                for(float i=0; i<= CoinR[5]; i++){
                    Invoke("SpawnCoin",0.3f);
                }
                diadromos= false;
            }

    
            foreach (GameObject thisEnemy in allSpawns){ 
            DoSlidingOpen(thisEnemy);
            DoSlidingClose(thisEnemy);
            }
        }

        public void SpawnCoin(){
            Vector3 randCoinPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(CoinR[0], CoinR[1]), CoinR[2], Random.Range(CoinR[3], CoinR[4]));
            Quaternion CoinQ = new Quaternion(90,90,0,0);
            GameObject spawned = Instantiate(coin, randCoinPos, CoinQ);
            allSpawns.Add(spawned);
        }


    private IEnumerator DoSlidingOpen(GameObject eachcoin){
        
        StartPosition = eachcoin.transform.position;
        Vector3 endPosition = StartPosition + SlideAmount * SlideDirection;
        Vector3 startPosition = eachcoin.transform.position;

        float time = 0;
        while (time < 1)
        {
            eachcoin.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        }
        
    }

    

    private IEnumerator DoSlidingClose(GameObject eachcoins){

        StartPosition = eachcoins.transform.position;
        Vector3 endPosition = StartPosition;
        Vector3 startPosition = eachcoins.transform.position;
        float time = 0;
        while (time < 1)
        {
            eachcoins.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPosition, endPosition, time);
            yield return null;
            time += Time.deltaTime * Speed;
        }
        
    }
}
```

It's kind of a mess at this point, but I have tried a lot of different things. I am trying to reuse functions (DoSlidingOpen & DoSlidingClos) from another script for opening and closing doors.

Edit: What is not happening is that the coins, which do actually spawn and are added to the list, don't move at all, they don't even glitch around.  I tried to use

```
Invoke("DoSlidingOpen(thisEnemy)",2);
Invoke("DoSlidingOpen(thisEnemy)",2);
```

Which didn't work as well, not sure if invoke can take variables input or not. I also tried doing foreach() inside the functions instead of in Update, also didn't work.

Comment: you need to explain whats not happening then.. but you look to be trying to start a whole bunch of the coroutines every frame while the coroutines seem to do possibly oposite things.. but will be running semi concurrently.. and repeatedly starting at 0 and going nuts

Comment: @BugFinder , I have tried using invoke with a wait time, and also tried to call only one of the coroutines, but they didn't move at all. It's not that they are going nuts or anything, they don't move at all

Comment: Probably because it does 1 step forward one step back and stays in the same position. You should call those coroutines once. Not every frame. And call one. When thats done it calls the other

Comment: If your goal is to simply have them move up and down for visual effect, I'd recommend animating them in the Unity Animation Editor instead, even if its functional instead of just visual I'd still recommend looking into animating them. The built in Animation Editor really good for creating simple animations on the fly (such as floating an object between two points) https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-CreatingANewAnimationClip.html

Comment: @A-Fairooz It worked that way, after a lot or work and researching, thanks